# What's the minimum number of squadmates and missions I need to be able to use the Omega 4 Relay?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I wanna do a speedrun on insanity and unlike the other questions here, I'm looking to kill all my squad except for Morinth. What's the fastest way to achieve this? If I only want her to survive should I bring her along to the final battle?

Also, I know that I need at least 2 people surviving for Shepard to survive. Well, I'm also looking to kill him on this run.

Comment: Quite the masochist eh? I am curious though, and correct me if I am wrong here, but doesn't Shepard have to survive for any squad mates to survive, including Morinth?

Comment: @Xantec Nope. You can have one squadmate left and sheppard will still die.

Comment: @MrSmooth does it show that squadmate returning to the Normandy and escaping (assuming you got the upgrades) or are they assumed lost (and dead) in the Collector base? i've never thought to do that before, so forgive my curiosity.

Comment: @Xantec What happens is, as you're returning to the Normandy, your crewmate jumps on board, and then as you jump to try to grab onto the Normandy, if you have 2 crew members, they'll help you up, if you have one, they can't catch you, and you fall, leaving your one crew member and joker as the only people left alive (plus whatever "extra" crewmembers you saved)

Comment: @MrSmooth, that must be dependent on other factors too, and possibly WHICH crew member survives the final mission. Because I have actually had one of my two squaddies in the final mission die and then still made it back and on to Normandy and escaped safely. (I can't remember at this point who the survivor was though.)

Comment: @eidylon I'm pretty sure you would have had 2. If you only have one left, they fail to pull shepard up because they can't shoot at the collectors AND pull you up.

Comment: No, I definitely lost one. Because I remember he died during the battle, and I didn't revive him before the cut scene, and Shepard and the other ran back to the Normandy...and I was REALLY pissed off at myself for not having revived him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at 2 for your team and 1 for each role they play during the rescue/assault that are not in your party. As I recall you need someone to do the infiltration, another to do the biotic shield and one other for the fire team, so that is at least <del>4</del> 5 allies. I don't recall offhand any other roles.

Comment: You also need two people to lead fire teams (assuming that the first team leader dies).

Comment: @Adeese right, updated.